# Position Absolute - Negative Right and Top: Internet Explorer Bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a floating dialog box that has a close button on the right top side. It works great with FF and Chrome and also with IE 9 (when also browser mode changes, it seems compatible with IE7 through IE9). But on IE 8, close button is not shown.

Is there any solution to this problem that IE has ?

```
.dBox
{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 91;
}

.dBox .dContent
{
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dBox .dButtonClose
{
  background-image: url("img/close.dbox.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 90;
}

<div class="dBox" style="display: block; top: 46px; left: 533px;">
  <div class="dContent">content here</div>
  <div class="dButtonClose" style="display: block;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be that there is no content in the .dButtonClose element. Have you tried entering text to see if it appears in IE8?

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong, although I don't have close.dbox.png so I had to substitute a red background instead.

Comment: It's working for me in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/HZPUh/1/ Can't reproduce.

Comment: The example of Alexey works fine in IE8 but fails in compatibilty mode. Try with http://jsfiddle.net/HZPUh/2/ I change right: -20px; with right: 0; in .dBox .dButtonClose

Comment: Its working for me but try these:
1. Check that your image is referenced correctly.
2. May be some IE z-index stack issue. Make the z-index of the button higher than the box.

Comment: png file is a 24x24px regular cross file' substitution is fine. I dont know how it could work for you Alexey, @sweetroll: I changed z-index to try different variations, normally it is same with dBox. IE is not working with IE8 on Windows XP.